# What is the best way to test Turbo Rails with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

I would like to have a good example on how to test Turbo with Rspec.
I copied a piece of turbo that I want to test.

Todo view:

```html
<!--- app/views/todos/_todo.html.erb --->
<li id="<%= "#{dom_id(todo)}_item" %>">
  <%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(todo) do %>
     <%= todo.title %>
     <%= link_to "Edit", edit_todo_path(todo) %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Todo edit view:

```html
<!--- app/views/todos/edit.html.erb --->
<%= turbo_frame_tag dom_id(@todo) do %>
  <%= render "form", todo: @todo %>
<% end %>
```

Todo form view:

```
<!--- app/views/todos/_form.html.erb --->
<%= form_with(model: todo, id: "#{dom_id(todo)}_form") do |form| %> 
   <!--- Errors... --->
   <%= form.text_field :title %>
   <%= form.submit %>
   <%= link_to 'Cancel', todo if todo.id %>
<% end %>
```